# OpenCV unable to write Images using imwrite

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to write a Mat format which I have created into a jpeg file but all I'm getting is an unhandled exception. From the documentation it says that

> Only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned (CV_16U) in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function.

So I created a Mat using the codes below:

```
Mat watermark(5,5,CV_16U);  
imwrite("C:\\watermark.jpg",watermark);
```

However, I am unable to write the image into jpeg. It works fine with BMP formats, but just not JPG or any other formats. I was advised to convert it to CV_16U or 8U but it didn't work as well and I do have write permissions to the C:\ directory.

Am I missing a step?  Or is there some other way I should go about saving an image into JPG using OpenCV?

Comment: Did you make sure that JPEG support for OpenCV is in place?  You can do a quick read test from <<http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html>> and see if it is supposed to be working on that setup.

Comment: Yes , I'm able to us eimread to read jpeg images . Its the writing (imwrite into formats other than bmp) that's killing me .

Comment: Strange.  Is there any error printed on console when it failed?  I see you said you have access to C:\ but, now that you have an issue, you might want to do a quick test of writing to C:\\Temp\\watermark.jpg.  Beyond this, I would suspect the format CV_16U where I am not much of an expert.

Comment: I get the same error when writing to both C:\\ Temp and C:\\ . 
"First-chance exception at 0x6eb1ee22 in MySIFT.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x6eb1ee22 in MySIFT.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000." This is the exception i got .

Comment: in a quick search, this looks pretty close to : <<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496712/opencv-unhandled-exception-when-writing-a-file>> - however, it is not answered there as well.  If you don't see any response, I recommend prepare to make a debug build and debug to see if there are any additional clues. (sorry for not being more helpful)

Comment: Try to `imwrite` a `BMP` image file instead and check how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using latest opencv (v3.0) or greater and windows x64 bit version some of opencv's functionality is not working correctly in debug mode... You have to run your code in release mode then everything will be run perfectly.

Issues I found with opencv3.1 and x64 bit - debug mode

1. imwrite(filename, image) getting exception (read access violation).
2. haarCascade.detectMultiScale(...) detects numerous amount of objects.

To fix these issues run application in release mode.

Still searching a good way to solve these problems in debug mode.

Answer (score -2):

This code works correct and make/rewrite "watermark.jpg":

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main() {    
    Mat watermark(5,5,CV_16U);
    imwrite("C:\\watermark.jpg",watermark);
    return 0;
}
```

I have Win7, Wascana Eclipse(MinGW GCC compiler), Opencv 2.4.5

Comment: This is not really an answer, also this question is half a year old.