# OpenCV imwrite params read access violation

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

A very simple question...why am I getting a read access violation error with this code?

```
cv::Mat laserSpeckle = Mat::zeros(100,100,CV_8UC1);
imwrite( "C://testimage.jpg", laserSpeckle );
```

When i attach a debugger and look into it further, it throws the exception at this snippet in grfmt.cpp.

```
if( params[i] == CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY )
        {
            quality = params[i+1];
            quality = MIN(MAX(quality, 0), 100);
        }
```

It occurs with .png and .tiff too. Im an OpenCV newbie, my apologies if this is something really simple. I am using Qt for what its worth.

Comment: Why does the destination path has two forward slashes (//)? Windows addresses paths with back slash (\), but since it is the "escape" character on programming, we have to use two of them together "\\".

Comment: my mistake...changing them to two backslashes made no difference though.

Comment: Windows can use forward slashes for most file operations unless you need the extended path lengths using the ` "\\?\"` prefix.

Comment: Did you try using one forward slash only?

Comment: I do not think the problem has anything to do with the path but its hard to help with only this information.

Comment: those are the only two lines in the function...im not sure what other info I can get you.

Comment: are you compiling in debug or release mode? are you linking against debug or release mode of openCV libraries?

Comment: Did you build OpenCV yourself? If yes, can you check if the option `WITH_JPEG` was enabled.

Comment: What @Micka said is very important. Remember it is not generally safe to use debug dlls in a release application or release dlls in a debug application. It is also not safe to use dlls from some other version of Visual Studio. All of these will cause eventual heap corruption due to having more than 1 independent heap and other incompatibilities. You can not allocate memory in 1 heap and free it in a second.

Comment: @nils, that was it...i forgot to check the options when i was building OpenCV. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: @user1003131 Great! I rewrote that comment as a proper answer for others who stumble over this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you build OpenCV yourself? If yes, make sure that the option `WITH_JPEG` is enabled when you configure your build files:

```
cmake ... -DWITH_JPEG=ON ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with bmp format:

```
cv::Mat laserSpeckle = cv::Mat::zeros(100,100,CV_8UC1);
cv::imwrite( "C://testimage.bmp", laserSpeckle );
```

Your code also works on my computer. However, it seems that on some systems it works only for bmp images. I saw similar issues reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189492/opencv-unable-to-write-images-using-imwrite) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496712/opencv-unhandled-exception-when-writing-a-file%3E%3E).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save image with alpha channel you should use png format. It is described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the **debugger** **version** **(x64)** if you build the code using the **release** **version** **(x64)** it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case c++ Code Generation settings were wrong
Should have been Multithreaded DEBUG dll MD